# Spring error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I learn spring and I have a problem:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/PanTau_acc/Desktop/SPRING/target/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.donutek] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMav

en.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.donutek] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

When I run the project with my entity `LoginLog`.

```
  import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "login_log")
public class LoginLog extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

    private Date date;
    private String ip;
    private User user;

    public LoginLog() {
        //
    }

    public LoginLog(Date date, String ip, User user) {
        this.date = date;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

`Base object is:`

```
    @MappedSuperclass
public class BaseObject {

    private Long id;

    /**
     *
     * @return true if the entity hasn't been persisted yet
     */
    @Transient
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id == null;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

`applicationContext.xml` is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
           "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.donutek.**.*"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.donutek.**.domain"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="com.donutek"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I think, that problem is in `public LoginLog(Date date, String ip, User user)`, because when i run the code without `User user` in `LoginLog` class, it's normaly working.

Can you help me?

Thank you for your advice.

Spring version is: `4.2.4.RELEASE`

**EDIT:**
`user.java` is:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseObject {

    /**
     * Login, unique
     */
    private String email;
    /**
     * Secret for signing-in
     */
    private String password;
    /**
     * Date of user registration
     */
    private Date dateRegistration;
    /**
     * User nick name
     */
    private String nickName;
    /**
     * State of user accoutn
     */
    private UserState userAccState;

    public User() {
        //
    }

    public User(String email, String password, String nickName) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.dateRegistration = new Date();
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.userAccState = UserState.acc_waitingForActivated;
    }

    @Column(unique = true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getDateRegistration() {
        return dateRegistration;
    }

    public void setDateRegistration(Date dateRegistration) {
        this.dateRegistration = dateRegistration;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    public UserState getUserAccState() {
        return userAccState;
    }

    public void setUserAccState(UserState userAccState) {
        this.userAccState = userAccState;
    }

}
```

`persistence.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="com.donutek"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="true" />

            <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**EDIT 2:**
`full stacktrace`: 
(a can't add stacktrace, because is to long).
Link:
http://pastebin.com/LkgwqtJZ

Comment: Did u create persistence.xml and gave it's reference while declaring entityManagerFactory bean in xml?

Comment: the stacktrace you've attached does not show the problem. can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @Funtik Thank you for your reply, i add link to post (section edit 2).

Comment: I am not sure with your persistence unit name com.donutek , can you try without giving a dot something like donutek

Comment: @abdulrafique : i test with "donutek" and same problem (same error log)

Comment: It seems like Spring is not able to find your persistence.xml.

Comment: Can you try like this: <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence-booking.xml"/>    Note the classpath with a *

Comment: @abdulrafique but if i delete `private User user;` from `LoginLog`, it working

Comment: also check that your persistence.xml is copied in META-INF runtime folder which server uses,(i mean deployed folder)

Comment: Ok, so the problem is mapping of your LoginLog and User, can you define annotation @OnetoOne for your table login_log and user.Basically you need a join between two tables. Also attach snapshot of your table column names for login_log and user

Comment: @abdulrafique : Do you mean to `@OneToOne` before each parameter?

Like this:   
`@OneToOne
private Date date;`
`@OneToOne
private String ip;`...

Comment: Buddy it dpends on your table structure , you do one to one joins if two tables are to be joined so in your case to join login_log and user , you will have to put annnotation only on User object in Login_Log table. Also if you can share your table columns of login_log and user, I will be able to comment better

Comment: @abdulrafique :  Thank you for your replye, I put `@OneToOne` only on User object in Login_Log table. But i get a same error. I generate table using code, you can look in my post how are look my table (login_log and user)

Answer (score 0):

Provide hibernate mapping for the User object in LoginLog class:

Example:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "email", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: It's work, but when I save object to database, i get error:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.donutek.domain.LoginLog.user -> com.donutek.domain.User
`

Comment: `User u = userDao.findByEmail("mujemail@seznam.cz"); //really exist

System.out.println(u.toString()); //User{email=mujemail@seznam.cz,.....

LoginLog ll = new LoginLog(new Date(), "IP", user); //ok

loginLogDao.save(ll); //fail`

Comment: Hope you are annotating Date column properly. like @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) public Date getDate() {}

Comment: Yes. Now i have `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) `. The error is only in **reading**. If you create a `user` to store and then store `loginlog` everything is ok. But when i read `user` from db and then i want save object `LoginLog`.

Comment: **ERROR:** `  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.donutek.domain.LoginLog.user -> com.donutek.domain.User`

Comment: PUT cascade=CascadeType.ALL) on user column like this: @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)